# How to sort 2 dimentional array by the 4th value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know the answer aren't missing on this one but bear with me, I've tried many solutions and I am still having trouble sorting a 2-dimensional array by the 4th value using JavaScript.

Here's what the list looks like (the array might contain an unlimited amount of list) :

```
colors = [[247, 247, 247, 429, 1], [132, 128, 132, 2, 1], [37, 29, 37, 649, 1]]
```

the output should be :

```
colors = [[37, 29, 37, 649, 1], [247, 247, 247, 429, 1], [132, 128, 132, 2, 1]]
```

Here's what I tried :

```
colors.sort(function(a,b){
    alert(a[3] - b[3]);
});
```

The code above returns, `NaN`, I'm not sure why...

---

If it can help the python equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve would be :

```
sorted_colors = sorted(colors(u), key=lambda x: -x[3])
```

Comment: `alert` is a poor debugging tool, better use the `console`. And since your sorting-function doesn't return anything your Array should not get sorted at all. But I don't see anything that would print `NaN` in this code.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I had to return instead of alerting it, what an amateurish mistake I've made... The answer was under my nose.

Comment: and be careful, unlike the `sorted()` function in python, `Array#sort()` doesn't return a sorted copy of the array, but it mutates the array itself; and returns it. If you want a sorted copy you have to manually/explicitely copy the array before sorting. Like `sortedColors = colors.slice().sort(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback needs to return a number. You don't return the result of the subtraction, you just show it with alert. Remove the `alert()`, and return `b[3] - a[3]` to get the order you want.

```js
var colors = [[247, 247, 247, 429, 1], [132, 128, 132, 2, 1], [37, 29, 37, 649, 1]];

colors.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[3] - a[3];
});

console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You should have consider looking at the [Array#sort() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). That's not the correct syntax.

```
colors.sort(function(a,b){
    alert(a[3] - b[3]);
});
```

You should return the result not alert

```
colors.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[3] - a[3];
});
```

Comment: Plus OP seems to want in reverse order, so `b[3] - a[3]` should be used.

Comment: @sp00m Yeah. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function in `.sort()` requires you to return a value. You are only alerting a value.

Here is a working example:

```
var colors = [[247, 247, 247, 429, 1], [132, 128, 132, 2, 1], [37, 29, 37, 649, 1]],
    sorted = colors.sort(function(a, b) { return b[3] - a[3]; }); // DESC
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing when you write alert(...), you must return the result, use this :

```
colors.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[3] - a[3]; // b - a when you are sorting 9->1, a-b otherwise
});
```